# I cannot use the # symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\text{I can't use the #-symbol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to be more specific than other questions...

Comment: Table 1 in the [LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @AgapeGal'lo I'm not sure if this is the correct way of using this site. Anyhow, if your question gets closed as a duplicate, people will still find your question (only marked as closed) _and_ will see the linked duplicate, where they can learn more. Anyhow, searching for ``You can't use `macro parameter character #'`` returns a handful of questions with the same problem... (By the way, I didn't downvote your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: you need to use `\` in front of the `#` symbol:

```
\#
```